# Click event on jquery-added element

Tags: jquery

I add an element with its own unique id using jquery and after that i want to chek a click event on that added element using its id.

Here is the code and it doesn't work for some reason.

I'm a new to this programming stuff, so maybe I don't see something obvious.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#type").click(function () {
            $(".footer").prepend('<div id="next">
                         <a id="next" href="#">
                         <img class="image" src="#" alt="next"></a></div>');
            $("#next").click(function () {
                $(".current")
                    .removeClass("current")
                    .addClass("done")
                    .next()
                    .removeClass("notdone")
                    .addClass("current");
            });
        });
```

Comment: Use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically created elements. You have `});` missing at the end your code should work

Comment: Thanks, that link was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe `event delegation` for that,

```
$(document).on("click", "#next", function () {
    $(".current")
        .removeClass("current")
        .addClass("done")
        .next()
        .removeClass("notdone")
        .addClass("current");
});
```

This will bind events to dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0):

As you are dynamically adding the next element, you need [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

also you are prepending element with same id `next` on each click on `type`. replace with class as next and use:

```
  $('.footer').on("click", ".next", function () { 
              $(".current")
              .removeClass("current")
              .addClass("done")
              .next()
              .removeClass("notdone")
              .addClass("current");
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$("#type").click(function () {
    $(".footer").prepend('<div id="next"><a id="next" href="#"><img class="image" src="#" alt="next"></a></div>');
}); 
$(".footer").on('click','#next',function () {
    $(".current")
        .removeClass("current")
        .addClass("done")
        .next()
        .removeClass("notdone")
        .addClass("current");
});
```